# why solace connection refused, and resumes after restart

Tags: spring-jms, solace, solace-mq

I have a app will connect to solace using spring jms, and solace server maintain yesterday, after that my app always says `Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://xxx, scheme=tcp://, host=xxx' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 190521, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1) Connection attempt failed to host 'xxx' ConnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: (Client name: ceaaa391610d/1/#11ba492e839/CfXgqoqM62   Local port: -1   Remote addr: xxx  Remote port: 55555) - Error communicating with the router. cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ((Client name: ceaaa391610d/1/#11ba492e839/CfXgqoqM62   Local port: -1   Remote addr: xxx  Remote port: 55555) - )`

I checked the app logs, above logs will appear every 8s, but seems I dont setup any timeout value in my app.

Solace connection base on `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and `org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory`, use `JmsTemplate` to send message.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
            <artifactId>sol-jms</artifactId>
            <version>10.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

do you know why it works after restart, also any idea of the Client name info there?

Will Appreciated for any help!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what the server maintenance was that triggered the issue? 

The log means that the client is not able to connect, the client will attempt to reconnect based on the properties that you've configured.